# Date d = new Date(0L); what is 0L mean in this Date?

Tags: java, date

```
Date d = new Date(0L);
```

what is `0L` mean in this `Date d`?

Comment: IMHO. This operation is not very useful. It is likely the developer wanted to give `d` an initial value, but didn't know what else to make it. It is likely this is not really required.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `0L` means the number zero of type `long`. It uses [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) to instantiate a Date that refers to zero milliseconds after (i.e. exactly) "the epoch", January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: So `new Date(0L)` will give you a Date Object for **January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT**. ( == the epoch)

Comment: I know it does. That wasn't a question ;-) 
Just an additional comment as to what "the epoch" means for those not clicking on the constructor link.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen what does 1L give?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen sorry I'm a swift developer converting android projects to iOS. I don't have eclipse or android studio to set a variable and read it's value. I was just wondering what epoch 1L would equal as I need to statically define it in my swift code

Comment: @user2363025: As the documentation states the parameter is the number of milliseconds since "the epoch", i.e. that would be January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.001 GMT

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen apologies Matt,  I saw that but any epoch converter I turn to online doesn't give the option to add a decimal point in the 'second' field, this was why I was wondering the epoch value

Answer (score 3):

0L is literal for Long Integer

Check : http://www.roseindia.net/java/language/java-literals.shtml

Answer (score 1):

`0L` is the number 0.  The`L` makes the number a`long` type.  By initializing a `Date` with`0L`, the date will represent January 1, 1970.